# Kentico: Long Query string loading page not found

Tags: query-string, kentico, kentico-12

Here is the setup:  migrating a page that takes an encrypted string from a query string and processes it to redirect to the wanted page.

The problem: The querystring is too long (8760) and the result goes to a page not found but if I truncate the encrypted string it to a much shorter length (2035 or less), it goes through, but of course it does not process)

More info:  I have so far added in the keys

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2097151" waitChangeNotification="1" maxWaitChangeNotification="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" enable="true"/>
```

I am at a loss,  and can only think there is some sort of hidden setting that I am missing but cannot figure it out.

The sample URL I am useing (to give you an idea of the length is:

```
http://localhost:1112/SSO/Consume?SAMLResponse=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
```

Comment: Use POST instead of GET. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: I don't think you understand,  the incoming URL (example above)  loads the page when it  is trimmed but gets redirected to a page not found when full length,  No post or get options at this point.  though there are some items in the link you presented which may be providing relevant info.

Comment: I've been doing this since the 90s but sure, do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using to test? [IE11 has URL length limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/939634) that are shorter than what IIS can handle.

In the tests in the link above, IE11 was able to handle up to "4043" characters in the URL.

It also appears there [are 2 places](https://blog.elmah.io/fix-max-url-and-query-string-length-with-web-config-and-iis/) where your update might need to be made.

```xml
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="8192" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and

```xml
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime ... maxQueryStringLength="8192" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In situations where a large amount of data needs sent to an application, like in a [SAML request](https://auth0.com/blog/how-saml-authentication-works/), the request is made as a POST with the data in the request body, rather than as a GET, so they are not subject to URL length limitations.

I also don't think this issue is a Kentico problem, unless you are seeing different results in a new WebForms application project with the same `web.config` settings.